Is there way to prebuild `node-gyp build` output?
I'm currently using node-rdkafka library, but it takes too long to build on ci/cd and local environment. Is there any way to prebuild native code and load per architecture and OS?
I know there is BUILD_LIBRDKAFKA=0 option on the library, but what I'm trying to do here is to skip the whole part of building native code.
